# Is there a way to run "in the background" code sent to the IBM backends?

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience

I use different qiskit backends to run my code. Since the maximum number of shots is $2^{13}$, sometimes I need to send the same code several times with a "different ticket". I am wondering if there is an equivalent way to run in the background, similar to the command `nohup`, to run qiskit code so that it runs all the instances one would like (or waiting in the queue as they are sent!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the jobs are sent in a non-blocking way. You can send all your jobs with `job = backend.run` and recover their results in a fully different session.

In order to fully recover your `Job` object from a backend, you need the job id (given you are running Qiskit 0.24 or later. See [@jyu00's comment](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/17371/is-there-a-way-to-run-in-the-backgound-code-sent-to-the-ibm-backends/17372?noredirect=1#comment25518_17372))

You can save your job ids like this:

```
jobs = []
for circuit in circuits:
  job = backend.run
  jobs.append(job.job_id())
```

Later, when the job is done, you can recover each `Job` object like this:

```
provider = IBMQ.load_account()
job = provider.get_backend(backend_name).retrieve_job(job_id)
```

Comment: You actually don't need the the backend name anymore. You can just do `provider.backend.retrieve_job(job_id)` (requires Qiskit 0.24). This syntax can also be used to retrieve jobs from retired backends.

Comment: Great hint! Updating the answer to reflect that.